# Openpyxl syntax error

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl 1.7.0 with python 3.3. I have used Excel 2007 and 2010 with the code

I created a basic excel 2007 workbook with cells A1-A21 filled with a random number in each one to test the code on their website. I saved the excel sheet as "thetest". The sheet that the numbers are on is called Sheet1. This is the code I ran.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = r'thetest.xlsx')

sheet_ranges = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Sheet1')

print sheet_ranges.cell('A14').value
```

I ran this code and got a message that highlighted the second "sheet_ranges" that has .cell after it and said invalid syntax. What is going on with this? Are there any good tutotrials for using this module as well?

Comment: In Python 3, print is a function. Use `print(sheet_ranges.cell('A14').value)`

Comment: This worked, thank you. I'm just getting the hang of programming.

Comment: I did not see @falsetru answer when I left my comment. I'm glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) should be used as function form.

```
print(sheet_ranges.cell('A14').value)
#    ^                              ^
```